# Change UITableViewCell height based on webview content

Tags: uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UIWebView nested within a UITableViewCell.

How can I adjust the cell's height depending on the content I load into the WebView (i.e. after it finishes downloading) ... ?

I have the tableview to set the heightForRowAtPath to be `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

`loadContentIntoWebview` is called by the owner of the TableView in it's `cellForRowAt` delegate methods.

I'm noticing `heightForRowAt` being called before `cellForRowAt` so my "solution" of setting the height based on the cell's webview's content size won't work.

---

```
import UIKit

class MyCell: UITableViewCell, UIWebViewDelegate {

  // MARK: - instance variables

  @IBOutlet weak var myWebview: UIWebView?



  // MARK: - lifecycle methods

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    myWebview?.scrollView.bounces = false;
  }

  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
  }



  // MARK: - private methods

  func loadContentIntoWebview(htmlString: String) {
    myWebview?.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
  }



  // MARK: - UIWebViewDelegate methods

  func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    // dynamically set WebView height
    let tempString = myWebview?.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.scrollHeight")
    var tempHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    if let n = NumberFormatter().number(from: tempString!) {
      tempHeight = CGFloat(n)
    }

    myWebview?.frame.size.height = tempHeight
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution ...

- In `webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)` set the constraint's
  height as in initial question but use `document.body.clientHeight`
- Blast a notification to tell the associated tableview to not `reloadData()`, but rather `beginUpdates()` then `endUpdates()`

---

```
@objc func handleWebviewFinishedLoading() {
    self.webview?.beginUpdates()
    self.webview?.endUpdates()
}
```

This seems to redraw the cells without reloading them :)

Answer (score 0):

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    if let cell :yourCell = self.yourTblVw.cellForRow(at: yourindexpath) as? yourCell{

        // set height of webview as per its content
        var frame = cell.webView.frame
        frame.size.height = 1
        let fittingSize = cell.webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
        frame.size = fittingSize
        cell.heightWebVwMain.constant = fittingSize.height
       }
```

where heighWebVwMain is constraint of your cell's webview's height. So you have to set this constant in cellforRow method also

Comment: So my WebView is within the cell ... so there is no self.tableview ... I could pass in a reference to it, but that seems bad. I've found a solution I will post below as an answer ... thanks for your post though :)

Comment: self.tableview is to get the cell